# Dynamic Combo box values

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:**

I have a user-form with a *comboBox*, *textBox* and *button*, the items of *comboBox* are the cells value in range (`(A1:A10)` for example).
If I enter a new text in *comboBox* which isn't in the range, I need to add this value to the range, and write it in the *textBox*, and if it is already exist I want to write it in *textBox* directly.
I tried to do it but I didn't succeed.
Can anyone help?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'cmbx.RowSource = "d2:d100"
    Dim cLoc As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")

    For Each cLoc In ws.Range("LocationList")
       cmbx.AddItem cLoc.Value
    Next cLoc

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly then I guess this is what you are tying to do?

For this, please ensure that in design mode, you set the ComboBoxes's `.Style` property to `0-fmStyleDropDownCombo`. This will ensure that you can type in the combobox. :) I have also commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding the code. But if you still do then simply post back.

**My Assumptions:** There is nothing below Cell `A10`

**Code:**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cLoc As Range

'~~> Prepare your form
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LookupLists")

    For Each cLoc In ws.Range("LocationList")
       cmbx.AddItem cLoc.Value
    Next cLoc
End Sub

'~~> This will do what you want
Private Sub cmbx_AfterUpdate()
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Check if the value is in the range
    '~~> If not then add it to the range and textbox as well
    If Not IFEXISTS(cmbx.Value) Then
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = cmbx.Value

        '~~> Delete the Named range so that we can re-create 
        '~~> it to include the new value
        ThisWorkbook.Names("LocationList").Delete

        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LocationList", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=LookupLists!R1C1:R" & lRow & "C1"
    End If

    '~~> Add to textbox
    TextBox1.Text = cmbx.Value
End Sub

'~~> function to check if the value is in the textbox or not
Function IFEXISTS(cmbVal As String) As Boolean
    For Each cLoc In ws.Range("LocationList")
        If UCase(Trim(cLoc.Value)) = UCase(Trim(cmbVal)) Then
            IFEXISTS = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cLoc
End Function
```